# Jenkins scripted pipeline to trigger job only when commits happen in Github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees, jenkins-groovy, crontrigger

We use CloudBees-2.138.2.2 Jenkins and have had lot of challenges to trigger jenkins jobs only based on commits in our Github repo. I am still looking for the exact working script for scripted pipeline and not declarative one.

so For example :- pipelineTriggers([cron('0-59/2 * * * *')]), works
but pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('0-59/2 * * * *')]), never works despite new commits

Comment: Did you consider such option as using 'Pipeline script from SCM' (via Jenkinsfile) with 'GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling' enabled? E.g., see [this](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline) example. It's a standard way of configuration and much easier to configure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of that but we want to establish entire pipeline using a single Jenkinsfile that uses scripted pipeline syntax. Hence the ask.

Answer (score 1):

was able to make it work using :-

pipelineTriggers([pollSCM('* * * * *')])  under properties

This way the job polls the repo every minute and will trigger build only when it detects a new commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following in your scripted pipeline

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])
```